# How can I turn ~/Documents into a symlink?

Tags: macos, dropbox, symlink

I keep my Documents in an encrypted directory in Dropbox (`~/Dropbox/encrypted`), which I then mount at `~/clear` when I log in.  On my other Macs, I have change ~/Documents to a symlink that points at `~/clear`, but trying to do the same on a new Mountain Lion machine doesn't work:

```
Pertinax:~$ pwd
/Users/drew
Pertinax:~$ ls
Desktop         Dropbox         Music           README.markdown tmp
Documents       Library         Pictures        bin
Downloads       Movies          Public          clear
Pertinax:~$ ln -sf clear/Documents .
ln: ./Documents: Permission denied
Pertinax:~$ ls -l@hd Documents
drwx------+ 3 drew  staff   102B Apr  5 15:02 Documents
Pertinax:~$ xattr -l Documents
```

It doesn't appear to have odd permissions or extended attributes, so I'm stumped.  I don't recall what I had done previously to make this work on my Lion and prior machines, or if I did anything special at all.

Comment: The "+" after the traditional UNIX permissions indicate an ACL (unlike the @ of an extended attribute), viewable with `ls -le`; all the premade subfolders of your home will have it set to "everyone deny delete", but attempting to `rm -Rf` it ought to succeed.

Comment: @Ryccardo - You are correct!  The `-e` flag on `ls` is what I was missing.  Could you make this answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: There it is :~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the default subfolders of your home have an ACL set to "everyone deny delete" (ACLs can be viewed with `ls -le` and stripped with `chmod -N`)

ACLs still don't affect a command run as the superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about executing the command as `sudo`? I've got a similar setup on my Mountain Lion Mac where I've just deleted my `~/Documents` folder and recreated it as a symlink to my `~/Dropbox` folder.